# Sliding Window object detector false positive windows

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I implemented the sliding window detector for detecting bikes in the scene using HOG features. However, in my implementation, I get a lot of false positive windows as well multiple overlapping windows on around the object.

According to Dalal & Triggs, in their work, they used the following function and non-maximum suppression to eliminate the overlapping bounding boxes.

1. B * f(x)

where B is the filter and x is the image and f(x) is the feature vector. I am not sure how the scores are calculated in this function. Can I get some advice how to compute window scores.

I used this lecture note as reference slide 6. http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231b_spring1213/slides/dpm-slides-ross-girshick.pdf